# @pytest individual test decorator to continue assert even after fail?

Tags: python, pytest

To stop the testing process after the first (N) failures:

```
pytest --maxfail=2
```

what I want is

```
@pytest.some_decorator
def test_one(data):
... #do something
    assert feature1...
    assert feature2...
    assert feature3...
```

This @pytest.some_decorator should run all assert statements even after the first one fails. It cannot be parameterized as it's a feature of the data.

Is this possible? really doesn't make sense to write multiple tests for tests like this for me.

Comment: Most test frameworks have a `soft assert` method you can use instead of `assert`, that gives you the ability to continue a test even after one of the asserts fail.  I would look into PyTest soft asserts and see if they have something like that

Comment: Pytest itself does not have that (the pytest philosophy is to use only simple asserts), but there is a plugin [pytest-check](https://github.com/okken/pytest-check) that provides a possibility to do this (though not via asserts).

Comment: @MrBeanBremen pulled this from it's docs but it's not working as expected. Have you used it like this before? it fails after the first test. def test_multiple_failures():
    with check: assert 1 == 0
    with check: assert 1 > 2

Comment: @JD2775 runs through terminal, want a decorator

Comment: @MrBeanBremen got it working using the pytest built in check functions but the contextManager way is preferred

Comment: @tigertiger - yes, I just tested it again and it works fine for me. I don't like the context manager form much because you have to add a new one for each assert, but it works. Note that you need pytest >= 6.0.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the normal `assert` then you're basically wanting to go back inside a function after the function has exited.

You can do that with [fuckitpy](https://github.com/ajalt/fuckitpy). See https://github.com/ajalt/fuckitpy#as-a-decorator Maybe there's a way to modify it so it only continues after `AssertionError`s and not just any exception.

Answer (score 0):

Split tests with a single assert per test. Use `@pytest.mark.xfail()` decorator to mark tests you are expecting to fail.

Comment: xfail is something different, I did use that for a different test. pytest_check is doing what I wanted so it is working. Was hoping their context manager method would work, (with pytest_check: assert ...)  but no luck; their inbuilt functions worked fine

Comment: I'm not completely undertand. You have an exception which is 'OK' for test? There is `with pytest.raises...` for that.